# How do I pull out certain words from a string?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, swift3

I have two arrays of strings that I join together with a "-" separator which turns it into a full string like so `"art-movies-sports"`. The code is below:

```
let myFirstArray: [String] = ["art", "movies", "sports"]
let firstJoinedArray = myFirstArray.joined(separator: "-")

let mySecondArray: [String] = ["art", "movies", "sports"]
let secondJoinedArray = mySecondArray.joined(separator: "-")
```

What I want is to call something when 3 or more words from `"art-movies-sports"` in firstJoinedArray are equal to 3 or more words in secondJoinedArray. In this case, it will of course be correct. In a nutshell, I want to have much longer strings (both containing different words but have 3 or 4 that are the same) and I want to call something when 3 or more are correct. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if the first and the second array have *any* three elements in common? Does the order matter? Or do only *consecutive* common elements count? How are the "joined arrays" (which are strings) relevant? – A non-trivial example might be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR These Arrays are just examples. I don't want any specific strings to match, I just want any of the 3 to match. So if they both contained "Dog, cat, mouse", something would run etc

Comment: Answer given by @connor seems to work. Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the arrays directly, rather than the string. Then create sets out of them, so you can find their intersection:

```
let set1 = Set(myFirstArray)
let set2 = Set(mySecondArray)
let inCommon = set1.intersection(set2).count // If this is >= 3, do stuff
```